# How to improve runtime of an sql query in excel

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access

I am trying to query an access table from excel. It works, but it is really slow. The running time of the query (~ 60000 data sets) in excel is more than 4 minutes, the same query in access needs less than two seconds. Unfortunately, I can't use an access query, since in a later version, I am going to use parameters, which will be stored in excel. Perhaps somebody of you has some tips for me how to improve the runtime?

```
Sub SQL()
Dim Cn As Object
Dim rs As Object
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strConnection As String

Application.Cursor = xlWait

    Set Cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=path.accdb"


    strSQL = "SELECT Name,adress,city,street,month,company, sum(amount), sum(price) FROM Table Group by Name, adress,city,street, month, company order by sum(amount) DESC"

    Cn.Open strConnection

    Set rs = Cn.Execute(strSQL)

    Worksheets("Table1").Range("a:x").ClearContents


    Worksheets("Table1").Range("a2").CopyFromRecordset rs
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing

    Application.Cursor = xlDefault


    End Sub
```

Comment: Try using arrays instead of sql, that's much faster

Comment: Thank you. Yes I mean rows. I am a beginner in vba, how can I use arrays?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y13tek7e.aspx can get you through basics of arrays

Comment: On the other hand, I don't think arrays are going to enhance the speed altogether since there are no calculations involved in your sql query, just a basic selection.

Comment: The runtime in Access only displayed partial result. In addition, you don't even need VBA. Look at the "Data" menu tab in the Excel toolbar.

Comment: How do the running times compare when you eliminate `ClearContents` and `CopyFromRecordset` from the Excel VBA procedure?

Comment: In this case it is much faster. The bottleneck is the copy process from access to excel...

Comment: How long does it take to open the access database? I ask because when you query access from excel, it needs to actually open up an instance of that database. If you are working off a network or the DB is big. That could be your bottleneck